# How to separate URL into to parts

Tags: php

I have bellow URL and storing in one variable which is `$currentURL`.

```
$currentURL = http://localhost/example/villa-search/page/2/?features=Beachfront%2CCook%20Services%2CGarden%2CPrivate%20Pool%2CSea%20View
```

Now I want to break URL in to section and store in two different variables

First Part is:

```
http://localhost/example/villa-search
```

second Part is:

```
/page/2/?features=Beachfront%2CCook%20Services%2CGarden%2CPrivate%20Pool%2CSea%20View
```

How to make this possible?

Comment: You can use regular expression to do so.

see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438523/php-regex-on-url-split-into-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and get components from it and re-construct your desired format from it.
And then use [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) the query part obtained from parse_url().